# Possible to Define Filter in Fluent NHibernate FluentMappings?

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, automapping

When using auto mappings in Fluent NHibernate, you have the ability to do something like:

```
                _configuration =
    Fluently.Configure().
        Database(
        MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2000.ConnectionString(
            @"some connection string")
        )
        .Mappings(
        m => m.AutoMappings.Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<GSAContract>().Where(x=>x.Namespace == "SomeNamespace")))
        .BuildConfiguration();
```

I'm looking to be able to do something similar with FluentMappings, but I can't seem to figure out a similar behavior (filtering on Namespace).

Comment: Why do you want to filter your classmaps?

Answer (score -1):

If you won't supply a ClassMap for a class it won't be mapped.

Comment: And yeah, I know it's not the answer to your question. I don't know of any way to do what you actually asked for.